# My formencode.variabledecode is returning an empty list - Pylons

Tags: python, forms, pylons, formencode

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="blah-0" value="test" />
<input type="text" name="blah-1" value="another test" />
```

Controller:

```
class myvalidator(formencode.Schema):

    allow_extra_fields  = True
    filter_extra_fields = True

    test = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.String())

def form_posted(self):
     form_result = myvalidator().to_python(request.params)

     print form_result
```

What I'm trying to get is a list returned. Something like:

```
> print form_result['blah']
['test', 'another test']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is form_posted a method of the class myvalidator? I'm not familiar with pylons, but it seems the indent isn't right or the code are from different part of your program.

Comment: The indents and scopes are all correct. I just trimmed it down for the post.

Comment: It looks like `form_posted` is a method of something since it's first argument is `self`. Is `test` really a `myvalidator` class attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is incomplete but you must decode your variables before:

```
from formencode import variabledecode

def form_posted(self):
     decoded = variabledecode.variable_decode(request.params)
     form_result = myvalidator().to_python(decoded)
     print form_result
```

You also should change that line if you want blah:

```
test = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.String())
```

to:

```
blah = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.String())
```